# How to search for "foo ba*" in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

There are `match_phrase` queries in Elasticsearch and there are also `wildcard` queries. Is there a way to combine the two to search something like "foo ba*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in using "Span Queries". As mentioned in the official documentation:

> Span queries are low-level positional queries which provide expert control over the **order** and **proximity of the specified terms**.

The final query would look something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                { "span_term" : { "field" : "foo" } },
                { "span_multi" : { "match": { "wildcard": { "field" : "ba*" } } } }
            ],
            "slop" : 0,
            "in_order" : true
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

1. `slop` is used to mention how far can the different "span terms" be. Here since we want them to be adjacent to each other, we specified the `slop` to be 0.
2. `in_order` is for whether the order of terms is important. In our case, it is - hence `true`.